# why no extension of table of content in jupyter notebook?

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I did install NBExtension using below command without any error. I do see NBExtension tab when loging to jupyter notebook. However, I don't see table of table icon inside jupyter notebook. so I am wondering what I am missing to get this table of content working? Thanks for helping

conda install -c conda-forge jupyter_contrib_nbextensions

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi anyone can help me here? I tried to google it for a long time and I cannot find the solutions. Thanks

Comment: ok, i finally fixed it, use both pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions and jupyter contrib nbextension install --user works. check this website, https://diauxicshift.wordpress.com/2018/04/20/installing-table-of-contents-extension-to-jupyter-notebook/